# How do I find and select a value from multiple cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table which looks like this:

```
Date       | Type | Value
2017-04-28 | A    | 100
2017-04-28 | B    | 300
2017-04-28 | C    | 500
2017-04-29 | A    | 140
2017-04-29 | B    | 350
2017-04-29 | C    | 600
2017-04-30 | A    | 200
2017-04-30 | B    | 400
2017-04-30 | C    | 620
2017-04-30 | D    | 240
```

And I want to make a formula that converts it to this structure:

```
Date       | A   | B   | C   | D
2017-04-28 | 100 | 300 | 500 | 0
2017-04-29 | 140 | 350 | 600 | 0
2017-04-30 | 200 | 400 | 620 | 240
```

Is this possible?

At the moment I have done a formula like this:

```
=IF(AND(DATEVALUE(A2)=E2;TRIM(B2)="A");C2;"")
```

The problem with this is that it isn't dynamic as it only compares a given cell. I would like it to compare with all the combos of Date and Type (only unique ones exist) and then take that value and add to the new structure.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SUMIFS():

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$F2,$B:$B,G$1)
```

You may need the `;` instead of the `,` for the delimitor:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C;$A:$A;$F2;$B:$B;G$1)
```

[image]